# Windows Store won't launch

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, windows-store-app

On my Windows 10 machine (with latest updates), when I login with my user, search for 'Store' and click on the 'Store' result. It does nothing. Start bar doesn't even close, nothing.

When I login under my partner's account, the store works perfectly fine.

I've tried many different solutions ranging from powershell scripts, `wsreset.exe` and folder permissions but I can't get it to run at all.

Has anyone had this issue before or know some steps that do work?

I've also ran `sfc /scannow` and it said that it fixed some corrupted files.

`wsreset.exe` came back with error 'Invalid Registry'.

My existing Windows Store apps do load up fine on my machine I just can't load up the Store itself under my user.

The PC was originally upgraded from Windows 8.1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got it working.

After doing some digging and again re-creating my user account, I have discovered that the `AppData` for the Windows Store had been encrypted from my previous Windows 8 install. So this time when I recreated my account and copied over my files, I excluded the `Appdata` folder and the store now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, did a bit of googling, and landed on this solution ([source](http://windowsreport.com/windows-store-doesnt-open-windows-10/)):

1. Open the Start menu and in the Search field enter `Powershell`
2. Right click the Powershell icon, and choose "Run as administrator".
3. Enter: 
   `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}`
4. Press Enter to execute the command.

I've had to do it twice, but after the second time the problem hasn't come back.