# Windows Store won't start and no suggested solution works

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store

I have the same problem that apparently many people have, the Windows Store won't start. The icon in the Start Menu is greyed out and has a white circle with an exclamation mark in the lower right. If I try to start it, a window pops up for the blink of an eye and disappears immediately. No error message or anything.

I'm using Windows 10 on a computer that ran Windows 10 from the start (it wasn't updated from an older version, I installed Windows 10 after I got the computer with no OS on it). I'm not sure for how long the problem has been present. I do know it was working like half a year ago, which is when I last needed to install an app from it and I haven't used it ever since.

I have tried the following solutions to no avail:

1. Running `wsreset.exe`. It exists with the following error:
   [image: wsreset error]
2. Running [this troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/69e76f90-d54c-44cf-9851-c2d1542790db/run-the-troubleshooter-for-windows-apps). It says no problems were detected.
3. Running this command in an elevated powershell found [here](https://superuser.com/a/1072319/351703):
   `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}`
   (Gives me some cryptic blocks of text in red)

I'm not sure what else I could try. Really tired of this ... well ...
Any help is appreciated. If you need any additional information let me know.

Comment: Which build of Windows 10 are you using?  If you create a new user does the Windows Store work?  Have you used any tools to "disable Windows 10 spying" by chance?

Comment: Will install the latest one tomorrow. Create a new user? Why? Also how do I do that, I have never used more than one account on Windows 10 ... and no, no tools like that

Comment: What UWP are available to a user are decided when its created.  If you did something to disable them, it shouldn't effect, a new user.  How you create a user on Windows is well documented.  *The entire idea of a second user is to determine, if all user are effected, if they are the solution is more complicated.*  Can you confirm Universal Windows Applications like Settings, Calculator, and etc. all work?

Comment: Ok nevermind. I just installed the anniversary update and that seems to have fixed it, the Windows store is working again. Would still like to know what went wrong in the first place, but oh well ... Thanks anyway!